# ASP MVC Change the browser language?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multilingual

To change the language on my website I've been using ressources and this code:

```cs
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(languageCode);
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(languageCode);
```

It' working fine using the correct ressource.

But I have an address autocomplete which makes request to google and the response keep coming in the first language set in the browser and not the one I used.

How could I change that ?

Comment: I did find the answers to my question here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization
To make the geocoding use the correct language I just needed to specify the language when requesting the script file

Comment: Is it possible there is an attribute that specifies the language to return results in? Additionally, the control should be picking up the current culture for the browser and adjusting accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser language is set by the user, you cannot change that.

What google API are you using, maybe you can pass along a language parameter?